# Attempting to populate two arrays from two tables within a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

The end-result of all this should be that the arrays for description and pass should be populated and I should be able to echo them. However, only the descriptions will echo but the passwds do not echo. From all my testing, it looks like the $value variable is empty for the result1 query. I can not figure out how to use the $value in the second query.

I also get these two errors:
Notice: Undefined variable: pass in /var/www/html/manage/commit.php on line 60
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/manage/commit.php on line 60

```
// From manage.phones
$result = mysqli_query($con_manage,"SELECT * FROM phones");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $mac[] = $row['mac'];
    $mapped_to[] = $row['mapped_to'];
}

// From asterisk.devices
foreach($mapped_to as $value)
{
  $result = mysqli_query($con_asterisk,"SELECT description as description FROM devices WHERE id='$value'");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $description[] = $row['description'];
  }
  $result1 = mysqli_query($con_asterisk,"SELECT data as data FROM sip WHERE id='$value'");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $pass[] = $row['data'];
  }

}

// Echo the descriptions and passwds!
echo "Echo all descriptions:";
echo"\n";
foreach($description as $key => $value)
{
  echo "$value\n";
}

echo "Echo all passwds:";
echo"\n";
foreach($pass as $key => $value)
{
  echo "$value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query `SELECT data as data FROM sip WHERE id='$value'` has en empty result set. That's why `$pass[] = $row['data']` is never executed. Because you do not define `$pass` explicitly (e.g. by `$pass = array()` before your first `foreach` loop), you get the two errors when trying to `foreach($pass as $key => $value)`.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that when I try to call $value in the second query, it is blank and everything I've tried to repopulate $value[] from $mapped_to[] is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
$pass = array();
```

before the foreach loop

```
// From asterisk.devices
foreach($mapped_to as $value) { .... }
```

Comment: Thanks. This cleared the errors but the problem is that when I try to call $value in the second query, it is blank and everything I've tried to repopulate $value[] is not working.

Comment: did you try to `print_r($mapped_to);` before the loop?

Comment: I am an idiot. My query was returning an empty string. There is nothing wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$result1 = mysqli_query($con_asterisk,"SELECT data as data FROM sip WHERE id='$value'");`

to

`$result1 = mysqli_query($con_asterisk,"SELECT data as data FROM sip WHERE id='".$value."'");`.

You should do that for both of your queries. That's how you concatenate strings. Same thing with your echos

to populate your arrays, you should do

```
$description = array(); //initialize your array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   array_push($description, $row['description'];
}
```

Do the same for $pass

Comment: Thanks, that helps clean it up but the problem is that when I try to call $value in the second query, it is blank and everything I've tried to repopulate $value[] from $mapped_to[] is not working.

Comment: @TayKimchi You can't populate your arrays like this. Look at my updated answer

Comment: I am an idiot. My query was returning an empty string. There is nothing wrong with my code.

Comment: @TayKimchi Look at how I populate the array in my answer. Your way is not the right way..

Comment: Sorry, I only meant that my code was working when I posted it here. I was just looking for the wrong things in the database...

Comment: There is no reason to prefer `"SELECT data as data FROM sip WHERE id='".$value."'"` over `"SELECT data as data FROM sip WHERE id='$value'"`.